# .NET Framework 4.7.2. not installing (and no error messages)

Tags: .net, windows, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to install the .NET Framework 4.7.2. (and the .NET Developer Pack) on my system, but even though the installation runs successfully, after a final restart, the installation does not appear to take effect.

I verify the installation by running the Powershell command `Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | ForEach-Object { $_ -ge 461808 }`, which returns `False`.

- Here's a screenshot after I ran the installation: [image]
- I'm running Windows 10 Pro, Version 1709 (which is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems))
- I'm using [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net472) to download the framework and [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/net472-developer-pack) for the developer pack
- I used the [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/)
- When I run `Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\"` in Powershell I got the following:

> ```
>     Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
>
>
> Name                           Property
> ----                           --------
> 1033                           CBS           : 1
>                                Install       : 1
>                                Release       : 461308
>                                Servicing     : 0
>                                TargetVersion : 4.0.0
>                                Version       : 4.7.02556
> ```

- Here is the result from the log file:

> ```
> OS Version = 10.0.16299, SP = 0.0, Platform 2
> OS Description = Future OS - x64 
> MSI = 5.0.16299.15
> Windows servicing = 10.0.16299.188
> CommandLine = C:\4a6a5e0d263c86a82d1299\\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /web
> TimeZone = Eastern Daylight Time
> Initial LCID = 1033
> Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
> Operation: Installing
> Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 Setup
> Package Version = 4.7.03081
> User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled
> Number of applicable items: 6
> Exe (C:\4a6a5e0d263c86a82d1299\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
> Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
> Exe (C:\4a6a5e0d263c86a82d1299\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
> Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
> Exe (C:\4a6a5e0d263c86a82d1299\Windows10.0-KB4073120-x64.cab) succeeded and requires reboot.
> Exe (C:\4a6a5e0d263c86a82d1299\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
> Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
> Exe (C:\4a6a5e0d263c86a82d1299\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
> Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
> ServiceControl operation succeeded!
> Final Result: Installation completed successfully with success code: (0x80070BC2), "The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:02:31).
> ```

- Here is the info from "dd_SetupUtility.txt":

> ```
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:574]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:574]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:574]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:574]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /aupause
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:574]     INFO:       Pausing Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:574]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:574]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:605]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:605]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:605]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:605]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /screboot
> [07/10/2018-14:52:23:605]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /msureboot 461833
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       Expected minimum "Release" number: 0.
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       MSUReboot: Registry name "Release" contains value "461308".
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       MSUReboot: No need to force reboot.
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:638]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:669]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:669]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:669]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:669]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /auresume
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:674]     INFO:       Resuming Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:674]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-14:53:44:675]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:308]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:308]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:308]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:308]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /aupause
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:308]     INFO:       Pausing Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:308]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:308]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:339]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:339]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:339]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:339]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /screboot
> [07/10/2018-15:03:53:339]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:882]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:882]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:882]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:882]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /msureboot 461833
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:883]     INFO:       Expected minimum "Release" number: 0.
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:883]     INFO:       MSUReboot: Registry name "Release" contains value "461308".
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:883]     INFO:       MSUReboot: No need to force reboot.
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:883]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:917]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:918]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:918]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:918]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /auresume
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:921]     INFO:       Resuming Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:921]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-15:04:36:923]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:820]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:820]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:820]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:820]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /aupause
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:825]     INFO:       Pausing Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:825]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:826]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:854]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:854]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:854]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:854]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /screboot
> [07/10/2018-15:31:53:855]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:278]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:279]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:279]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:279]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /msureboot 461833
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:279]     INFO:       Expected minimum "Release" number: 0.
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:279]     INFO:       MSUReboot: Registry name "Release" contains value "461308".
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:279]     INFO:       MSUReboot: No need to force reboot.
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:279]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:329]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:329]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:329]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:329]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /auresume
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:337]     INFO:       Resuming Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:337]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-15:32:29:338]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:814]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:814]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:814]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:814]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /aupause
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:820]     INFO:       Pausing Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:820]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:820]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:837]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:837]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:837]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:837]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /screboot
> [07/10/2018-15:34:49:837]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /msureboot 461833
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       Expected minimum "Release" number: 0.
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       MSUReboot: Registry name "Release" contains value "461308".
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       MSUReboot: No need to force reboot.
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:416]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:447]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:447]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:447]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:447]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /auresume
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:463]     INFO:       Resuming Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:463]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-15:35:16:464]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:327]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:327]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:327]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:327]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /aupause
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:332]     INFO:       Pausing Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:332]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:333]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:359]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:360]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:360]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:360]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /screboot
> [07/10/2018-16:02:14:360]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /msureboot 461833
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       Expected minimum "Release" number: 0.
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       MSUReboot: Registry name "Release" contains value "461308".
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       MSUReboot: No need to force reboot.
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:466]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:494]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:494]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:494]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:495]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /auresume
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:500]     INFO:       Resuming Automatic Updates ...
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:500]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/10/2018-16:12:22:501]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:037]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:039]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:040]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:040]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /aupause
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:050]     INFO:       Pausing Automatic Updates ...
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:051]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:053]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:098]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:098]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:098]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:098]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /screboot
> [07/11/2018-15:23:41:098]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:439]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:440]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:440]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:440]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /msureboot 461833
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:440]     INFO:       Expected minimum "Release" number: 0.
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:441]     INFO:       MSUReboot: Registry name "Release" contains value "461308".
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:441]     INFO:       MSUReboot: No need to force reboot.
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:441]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:517]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:518]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:518]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:518]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /auresume
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:532]     INFO:       Resuming Automatic Updates ...
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:532]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/11/2018-15:25:03:534]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:31:16:296]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:31:16:296]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:31:16:296]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:31:16:296]     INFO:       Command Line: "C:\c6cdf215785fd3365f1a43f9044059\SetupUtility.exe" 
> [07/11/2018-15:31:16:297]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:207]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:208]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:209]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:209]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /aupause
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:216]     INFO:       Pausing Automatic Updates ...
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:216]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:217]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:252]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:252]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:252]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:252]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /screboot
> [07/11/2018-15:48:15:252]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:599]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:600]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:600]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:600]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /msureboot 461833
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:600]     INFO:       Expected minimum "Release" number: 0.
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:600]     INFO:       MSUReboot: Registry name "Release" contains value "461308".
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:600]     INFO:       MSUReboot: No need to force reboot.
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:600]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:660]     INFO:       Log file path: C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_SetupUtility.txt
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:661]     INFO:       ####################################################################################
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:661]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Started ****************
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:661]     INFO:       Command Line: SetupUtility.exe /auresume
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:673]     INFO:       Resuming Automatic Updates ...
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:673]     INFO:       ... succeeded.
> [07/11/2018-15:49:28:675]     INFO:       **************** SetupUtility Ended ****************
> ```

Comment: very random thought - install the x86 and x64 installs if you are desperate to try something.

Comment: No sign of any errors.  0x80070BC2 == ERROR_SUCCESS_REBOOT_REQUIRED == "The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted".

Comment: Did you reboot the machine after installation?

Comment: @AlexGhiondea-MSFT -- yes

Comment: @dochoffiday can you share the file version for clr.dll?